# How can I repair cracked stones around a drain in a wet room?

Tags: shower, stone

We've had two plumbers trying to fix this problem but the leakage to downstairs is still happening.  The second plumber recommended that we contact a wet room specialist to have a look at this.  He said also that we shouldn't use silicone to fix the cracks around drain.  Do you agree with him?  Even as a short-term solution to prevent any leakage?  Any other solutions - short or long - welcome.

Pictures attached:

[image: Wet room]
[image: Drain with cracks]
[image: Close up of cracks]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That looks just plain done wrong to me. The drain entrance should be **below** the membrane that should be **below** the stone. Cracks in the grout should have no impact on the waterproofing effectiveness. Drain entrance level with stone surface = designed to fail.

A minimally invasive fix would be to lay a membrane on the top of the current stone and lay new stone above that. Making the connection to the side wall membrane will be somewhat tricky - assuming that's even there, which I have to wonder about...

If you want to save the current stone the options are purely invasive/destructive; and that's if you can get the stone up without destroying it.

Comment: This is true, and even if the grout weren't cracked, tile and grout are not 100% waterproof so there would be water getting below the drain anyway.

Comment: I agree with this. That plastic catchment is evil. When I first saw it, I thought "get sledgehammer". Ecnerwal's suggestion is sort of the quick and dirty solution. The proper solution would be to take out the entire floor and redo it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm I’m not really sure what caused these cracks in the first place? Looks to me that you have a problem with overall poor craftsmanship, because even if stone on the floor has cracks under your drain there should be something called "cuff" or a "sleeve”. It is made out of plastic or some similar material, circle like shape with diameter bigger than drain, whose inner side goes inside the drain, and outer is connected with hydro insulation. Purpose of this element is to prevent situations like this. Long term solution is to change, at least partially stones on the floor, and this time with a sleeve. When it comes to short term solution and your plumber advice he is partially right: Silicon is a perfect surface for mold, especially in a rooms with high humidity level, like this one is, plus it is organic so it disintegrates. You can fix the leak with silicone, but you must change it from time to time (let’s say once in a six months, or when it turns black)

Comment: If I could accept your answer as well as the other, I would.  Really appreciate your effort and the insights you shared there.

Comment: Thank you for kind words. Never mind that, we are here to help, not to get points. It doesn't matter which answer you accept, as long you solve your problem.